# ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in ng2-file-upload

Tags: python, angularjs, json, angular, ng2-file-upload

I am using ng2-file-upload to send file in Post api.
so when i am printing structure of the file before sending it, its look like below structure

[image]

But, as you can see the error which come when i am sending that to one api

```
 this.ocrService.uploadDocument(doc).subscribe(response => {
   f.resetForm();
   this.router.navigate(['/ocr']);
  });
```

i am using flask in backend and angular four for front end. i had already tried

```
let doc = JSON.stringify(this.document)
```

but its showing error in this line also.
please help

Comment: What exactly is `doc`? Is that what the output is in your picture?

Comment: And when is this called, how does your template look like?

Comment: no, output shown there is from console.log(this.document). when i am doing this   let doc = JSON.stringify(this.document), this line through an error

Comment: i am using angular 4 template, so the have one line of code to upload data  const URL = 'http://localhost:3000/upload';                                                         public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL });         this through an error that  that header is there, you need to specify header. but i am not passing any header here

Comment: Are you just declaring `FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL });` nothing else?

Comment: And if so, when is this `this.ocrService.uploadDocument(doc)` called? And what is `doc`?

Comment: doc is this let doc = JSON.stringify(this.document), , i have one button, when i click that, FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL });  is called.                 
                                  this.ocrService.uploadDocument(doc), this is i am using too save other parameter , which i want to save with that